# Spring Data MongoDB - wrong collection name with inheritance

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, inheritance, spring-data-mongodb

I'm developing an application with Spring Data MongoDB. I use a base entity that serves as a superclass of all entities. Each entity therefore inherits from the base entity and has a @Document annotation with the desired collection name. Unfortunately, the class name of the base entity is always used as the collection name. When I run the following test, a collection "baseEntity" is created and the PersonEntity is saved there:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    @Field("_id")
    protected ObjectId id;

    @LastModifiedDate
    protected Date lastModified;

    @Version
    protected int version;
}

@Document(collection = "person")
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public class PersonEntity extends BaseEntity {

    private String salutation;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
}

public interface SaveDAO<T extends BaseEntity> extends MongoRepository<T, ObjectId> {

    @Override
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity);
}

@SpringBootTest
class SaveDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    private SaveDAO<PersonEntity> saveDao;

    @Test
    void testCreateEntity() {
        PersonEntity entity = new PersonEntity();
        saveDao.save(entity);
        // TODO assert
    }
}
```

I have already looked at various examples on the Internet and copied some code to try out (e.g. @Document also in the BaseEntity).
Also, I have already tried to debug the Spring Data code. I noticed the following: in SimpleMongoRepository.save(...) "baseEntity" is returned when entityInformation.getCollectionName() is called. However, I didn't get much further or found any more useful information.

Edit:
I just replaced the **SaveDAO extends MongoRepository<T, ObjectId>** with **SaveDAO extends MongoRepository<PersonEntity, ObjectId>**. Then the correct collection is created and used. So apparently it's because of my generic repository. Is there any solution to this (other than creating a separate repository for each entity)?